# Access volume profile indicators like FRVP inside pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am writing a Pine Script to create a real time scanner. In this I need to access the Fixed Range Volume profile indicator inside the pine script. Is there a way to do this or do I have to write my own code for this?

Also, I am working on a 5 minute interval data to create alerts. In my code I need to access a specific 5 minute interval of the last n days (example last 9 days). How do I do this?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
lastClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to write the code yourself. [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000707985-fixed-range-volume-profile/) is the explanation of how FRVP works. So, you can use it as a reference.
2. You could get your 5 min data via `request.security()` and store it in an array. With `timeframe.change("D")` you can see if it is a new day. Then simply use a counter for that and when it is 9, check out your array.